# Go: Why is my hashtable implementation so slow?

Tags: hash, go, hashmap, hashtable

So I'm trying to make a super light, deliberately memory heavy, yet very fast hashtable for very fast lookups where I don't care about memory usage and I don't care if it makes a rare mistake.

Basically it just creates a ginormous array (yes array, not slice), hashes a string using a modified FNVa hash (modified to give only a hash within the array bounds) and then saves or lookups up the value using the hash as the array index. In theory this should be the fastest possible way to store and retrieve a key=>value pair.

This is my benchmark:

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

const dicsize250 = 2097152000 // tested 115 collisions

type Dictionary250_uint16 struct {
  dictionary [dicsize250]uint16
}

func (d *Dictionary250_uint16) Add(s string, v uint16) {
    i := id(s,dicsize250)
    d.dictionary[i]=v
    return
}

func (d *Dictionary250_uint16) Delete(s string) {
    i := id(s,dicsize250)
    d.dictionary[i]=0
    return
}

func (d *Dictionary250_uint16) Exists(s string) bool {
    i := id(s,dicsize250)
    if d.dictionary[i]==0 {
        return false
        } else {
        return true
    }
}

func (d *Dictionary250_uint16) Find(s string) uint16 {
    i := id(s,dicsize250)
    return d.dictionary[i]
}

// This is a FNVa hash algorithm, modified to limit to dicsize
func id(s string, dicsize uint64) uint64 {
    var hash uint64 = 2166136261
    for _, c := range s {
        hash = (hash^uint64(c))*16777619
    }
    return hash%dicsize
}

var donothing bool
func main() {

dic := new(Dictionary250_uint16)
dic.Add(`test1`,10)
dic.Add(`test2`,20)
dic.Add(`test3`,30)
dic.Add(`test4`,40)
dic.Add(`test5`,50)

mc := make(map[string]uint16)
mc[`test1`]=10
mc[`test2`]=10
mc[`test3`]=10
mc[`test4`]=10
mc[`test5`]=10

var t1 uint
var t2 uint
var t3 uint
donothing = true

// Dic hit
t1 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
for i:=0; i<50000000; i++ {
        if dic.Exists(`test4`) {
            donothing = true
        }
}
t3 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
t2 = t3-t1
fmt.Println("Dic (hit) took ",t2)

// Dic miss
t1 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
for i:=0; i<50000000; i++ {
        if dic.Exists(`whate`) {
            donothing = true
        }
}
t3 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
t2 = t3-t1
fmt.Println("Dic (miss) took ",t2)

// Map hit
t1 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
for i:=0; i<50000000; i++ {
    _,ok := mc[`test4`]
    if ok {
        donothing=true
        }
}
t3 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
t2 = t3-t1
fmt.Println("Map (hit) took ",t2)

// Map miss
t1 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
for i:=0; i<50000000; i++ {
    _,ok := mc[`whate`]
    if ok {
        donothing=true
        }
}
t3 = uint(time.Now().UnixNano())
t2 = t3-t1
fmt.Println("Map (miss) took ",t2)

donothing = false
}
```

The results I get are:

```
Dic (hit) took  2,858,604,059
Dic (miss) took  2,457,173,526
Map (hit) took  1,574,306,146
Map (miss) took  2,525,206,080
```

Basically my hashtable implementation is a lot slower, especially on hits, than just using a map. I don't see how this is possible since `map` is a heavy implementation (in comparison) which doesn't ever have any collisions, and does a lot more calculations. Whereas my implementation is super simple and relies on having a massive array of all possible indices.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How much memory do you have in the machine? As far as I can see, you're playing around at about 4GB used with your array.

Comment: Please use the builtin benchmarking facilities. Your timings are like not representative of what's going on, and it will also make profiling much easier.

Comment: yup, using the testing benchmark functionality shows some more usable data, see my new answer ;)

Comment: @Jaochin Isaksson, I have 128GB of RAM in this machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you're using a very large amount of memory compared to the built-in map, but that's a trade-of you mentioned you wanted to make.

Use the standard libraries benchmark utilities. It will give you a solid base to work from, easier profiling access, and remove a lot of guesswork. I had a moment to cut&paste some of your code into a benchmark:

```
func BenchmarkDictHit(b *testing.B) {
    donothing = true

    dic := new(Dictionary250_uint16)
    dic.Add(`test1`, 10)
    dic.Add(`test2`, 20)
    dic.Add(`test3`, 30)
    dic.Add(`test4`, 40)
    dic.Add(`test5`, 50)

    // The initial Dict allocation is very expensive!
    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if dic.Exists(`test4`) {
            donothing = true
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkDictMiss(b *testing.B) {
    donothing = true

    dic := new(Dictionary250_uint16)
    dic.Add(`test1`, 10)
    dic.Add(`test2`, 20)
    dic.Add(`test3`, 30)
    dic.Add(`test4`, 40)
    dic.Add(`test5`, 50)

    // The initial Dict allocation is very expensive!
    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        if dic.Exists(`test6`) {
            donothing = true
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkMapHit(b *testing.B) {
    donothing = true
    mc := make(map[string]uint16)
    mc[`test1`] = 10
    mc[`test2`] = 10
    mc[`test3`] = 10
    mc[`test4`] = 10
    mc[`test5`] = 10

    b.ResetTimer()

    // Map hit
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _, ok := mc[`test4`]
        if ok {
            donothing = true
        }
    }

    donothing = false
}
func BenchmarkMapMiss(b *testing.B) {
    donothing = true
    mc := make(map[string]uint16)
    mc[`test1`] = 10
    mc[`test2`] = 10
    mc[`test3`] = 10
    mc[`test4`] = 10
    mc[`test5`] = 10

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _, ok := mc[`test6`]
        if ok {
            donothing = true
        }
    }
    donothing = false
}
```

Without the `ResetTimer()` call, the initial allocation of your backing slice dominates the benchmark time, and even when amortized across the runs it skew the results heavily. After the reset, the benchmark times look in order:

```
BenchmarkDictHit    50000000            39.6 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDictMiss   50000000            39.1 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapHit 100000000           22.9 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapMiss    50000000            36.8 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Your `id` function needs to iterate over a string. With strings, range doesn't iterate bytes, it looks for runes which is going to be more expensive. You will want to index the string directly, or possibly use `[]byte` throughout (about the same cost-wise). With better string handling, these are the final timings from my test.

```
BenchmarkDictHit    100000000           17.8 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDictMiss   100000000           17.2 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Comment: Good points. There is a non-`unsafe` way to iterate bytes of a string, though: `s := ""; for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ { fmt.Println(s[i]) }` [works](http://play.golang.org/p/0o3Oa-mDXF).

Comment: thanks @twotwotwo, don't know what I was thinking, and that's what I get for answering while tired.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the results from my version of [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb)'s original version of your benchmark:

```
BenchmarkDictHit    30000000            40.8 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkDictMiss   30000000            40.6 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapHit     100000000           20.3 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapMiss    50000000            29.5 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Under favorable circumstances, Go's map implementation can be quite fast. Overall, your benchmark is contrived and meaningless.